# socket.io connection event never fire

Tags: socket.io

server

```
var io = require('socket.io'),
UUID = require('node-uuid'),
gameport = 3000;

var db = {
    waiting_clients: []
};

var logic = {

};

var sio = io.listen(gameport);

sio.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    var client = {
        id: UUID()
    };

    socket.emit('news', client);

    console.log(client.id);

    db.waiting_clients.push(client);
});
```

test client:

```
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect({port: 3000},
function(e) { //'connect' listener
  console.log('client connected');
  client.end();
});
```

in test client console, it show "client connected". But there are no output in server console

Comment: try removing ``.sockets`` ? ``sio.on(...)``

Comment: I tried but still the same

Comment: Take a look at a step-by-step example on how to correctly use Socket.io: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a socket.io client to connect to a socket.io server.  Your code shows that you are trying to make a generic TCP connection to a socket.io server.  That will not work.  The lowest level connection will be established, but then the initial protocol handshake will fail and the socket.io server will drop the connection and you will never get the connection event.

Socket.io has its own connection scheme built on top of webSocket which is built on top of HTTP which is built on top of TCP.

So, to connect to a socket.io server, you must use a socket.io client that runs both the socket.io and webSocket protocol, not a plain TCP socket.